# How to convert int32x4_t to float32x4_t

Tags: neon

Can any one tell me how I can convert int32x4_t to float32x4_t by using neon intrinsics .
I am working on imx6 hardware with a9 processor .I am new to the neon .
Any help is appreciated .

Comment: So what do you mean by converting. Rounding the value or keeping the bits?

Comment: Sorry my mistake i got the  answer .This is done by using VCVT instruction .+

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
float32x4_t vcvtq_n_f32_s32(int32x4_t a, __constrange(1,32) int b);  // VCVT.F32.S32 q0, q0, #32
```